# Faster way to shift a decimal in Python to remove zeros?

Tags: python, math, optimization

I have a variety of numbers that are always bounded by 0 and 1. The numbers range in value such as

```
.9, .08, .00024, .00000507
```

My goal is to convert these numbers to the following

```
.9, .8, .24, .507
```

That is, I want to remove any zeros after the decimal point.

I have the following code to do this. Is there a way to do this faster in terms of performance?

```
import math
x=.009
n = int(-math.log10(x))
x *= math.pow(10, n)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Do you want a form of scientific notation or something?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Of course. These values are not absolute probabilities. I'm only interested in relative probabilities and it's just easier for our client to see them in this new form.

Comment: @FredLarson I do but without the Exponent/Power. What I listed above is exactly the form I'd like.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what "relative probabilities" and "absolute probabilities" are, but in my world, .000000507 and .507 are *vastly* different numbers and *doesn't mean the same thing by a longshot*. How can this help your client? (this is completely unrelated to what you're asking btw)

Comment: FWIW it's really hard to imagine a situation where the performance would matter here.

Comment: @DSM If you have to do this in addition to other computations, several millions of times, performance would matter.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If a client saw P(A) = 6.324e-7 and P(B) = 1.028e-6, they would get confused. But, if they saw P(A) = .06324 and P(B) = .1028, it would be easier for them to understand. These are not real probabilities, more of a "measure" using probabilistic approach.

Comment: Why not just divide them and present the ratio then?

Comment: So in reality you are scaling up *two* numbers by the same amount? Because I would imagine the client would be a bit unhappy if it learned that P(A) = 0.000000000009 was shown as greater than P(B) = 0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster method of doing it (gets faster with larger numbers):

```
def method2(x):
    while x < 0.1:
        x *= 10
    return x
```

Even faster:

```
def method3(x):
    while x < 0.01:
        x *= 100
    while x < 0.1:
        x *= 10
    return x
```

Funny method of doing it (slower than the question):

```
def remove_zeros(a):
    return float("0." + str(long(str(1+a)[2:])))
```

Comment: clever. would using strings be faster than the math method above?

Comment: And by that, I emphatically mean *only one **correct** way to find out*. You need to measure!

Comment: Actually string method was worse than the power method. But my loop method I added is actually faster. It becomes faster when the numbers are larger :)

Comment: @Selcuk cok iyi. I'll give this question some time before I approve your answer.

Comment: Note that in your `method3` the second `while` is useless. You can replace it with an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly your expected output but you might be able to use it.

If you store the numbers as Decimals you can just format them to scientific notation and discard everything but the base.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> numbers = ['.9', '.08', '.00024', '.00000507']
>>> decimals = [Decimal(n) for n in numbers]
>>> [format(d, '.2E')[:4] for d in decimals]
['9.00', '8.00', '2.40', '5.07']
```

I showed them formatted as strings here because it's more precise to instantiate Decimals that way, as it sidesteps floating point issues. If you start with numbers as a list of floats, in the third step you get:

```
[Decimal('0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625'), Decimal('0.08000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875'), Decimal('0.00024000000000000000608020578329870886591379530727863311767578125'), Decimal('0.0000050699999999999997388091914352070688210005755536258220672607421875')]
```

In this case it gives you the same answer, but it might not always.